# Finding a tap aerator when nothing to screw it on

Tags: plumbing, faucet

We just moved into this new flat and the taps are super powerful. We're trying to put tap aerators to limit the flow, but they don't really seem standard.
The kitchen one seems to be around 15mm (not super sure which part to measure) and the black part does not seem to be coming off, so there would be nothing to screw the tap aerator on.

[image: kitchen tap]

For the bathroom one, it seems to be a 24mm size, but it's not exactly round (some sides are flat) and there is also no part to screw the tap aerator on.

[image: bathroom tap]
[image: bathroom tap]

Does anyone know if it is possible to put tap aerators on these taps ? If yes, what would I be looking for, as it does not seem like I need a classic female/male thread.
Thanks for any help !
Coraline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both already have aerators built in, which is why there are no threads (or only internal threads, which *may* accept an adapter). Just close the valves under the sink partway.

BTW, aerators don't really limit flow. They just... aerate. They soften and spread the flow of water and introduce bubbles to make a smaller volume feel larger. That said, there are often flow-limiting devices ahead of the aerator, such as partial blocker plates.

Answer (score 1):

Your bathroom aerator has two flat sides to allow you to wrench on the aerator, which has a male thread, and the faucet has the female thread.  This might be the opposite of what you're used to, but it works mostly the same.  Replacement aerators sometimes have both male and female threads so just check that you have the right part to update it.

Comment: I see the flats now. Your eyes must be able to focus blurry photos better than mine.